# Trouble with JS, PHP & IE10 ... Can't see were it come

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer-10, dynamically-generated

I work in support team in my company and I have some trouble with IE10 ... and it's been a while since i try to resolve it !

I'll try to explain the best way possible my problem, I work for a big solution developped in PHP.

It's a CRM online, and there is contacts, companies, and events.
For each contact, there is a page for modify them, and in this page there is a button that let you load an image to attach it to this contact.

The way to load an image is Javascript, that is generated with PHP. In chrome or firefox it works really fine, no trouble anywere.
But in IE10, when I try to load the image, it does not work the first time, I have to reload another image, then reload the desired image to make it work but i still can't resize it.
At the end, when I submit the image, I have the alternative to resize the image after.

(I tried to put some screen but i need at least 10 reputation to post images ...)

HERE is my PHP function that generate the JS. If you have any question about it, do not hesitate to ask me.

```
public function _GenerateJS()  {
$sJS = '';

if(is_file($this->m_sSrc))
{
  $sJS .= "$(function(event) { ";
  $sJS .= "  $('#delmyimgajax_".$this->m_nUniqid."').show();";
  $sJS .= "} ";
}

$sJS =
"function beginCrop()
{
    var container".$this->m_nUniqid." = $('#launchcropbtn_".$this->m_nUniqid."').parent();
    var picname".$this->m_nUniqid.";
    var picpath".$this->m_nUniqid.";
    var UrlCropAjax".$this->m_nUniqid." = $('#input_url_crop_ajax').val();
    var UrlUploadAjax".$this->m_nUniqid." = $('#input_url_upload_ajax').val();
    var UrlDeleteAjax".$this->m_nUniqid." = $('#input_url_delete_ajax').val();
    var PathPhotoFull".$this->m_nUniqid." = '".$this->m_sFullSizePicturePath."';
    var PathJcropResources".$this->m_nUniqid." = '".$this->m_sResourcePath."jcrop/';
    var jcropRessPath".$this->m_nUniqid." = '".$this->m_sResourcePath."jcrop/';
    var cropboxState".$this->m_nUniqid.";
    var deleteBtn".$this->m_nUniqid.";

    var functions = {

        load:function() {
          var sImgSrc = PathPhotoFull".$this->m_nUniqid." + picname".$this->m_nUniqid.";

            $('#target').attr('src', sImgSrc);
            $('#previewdiv').append('<img src=\"'+ PathPhotoFull".$this->m_nUniqid." + picname".$this->m_nUniqid." + '\" id=\"preview3\" width=\"56px\" height=\"56px\"/>');
            $('#preview3').attr('src', PathPhotoFull".$this->m_nUniqid." + picname".$this->m_nUniqid.").load(function(){ functions.resizeColorbox(); });

            $('#fileupload').hide();
            $('#cropzone').fadeIn(1000);
            $('#picname".$this->m_nUniqid."').attr('value', picname".$this->m_nUniqid.");

      functions.loadScript('jquery.nelis.crop.js');

            functions.resizeColorbox();
        },

        deletePicture:function(filename){
            UrlDeleteAjax".$this->m_nUniqid."+='&filename='+filename;

        $.ajax({
        type: \"POST\",
        url: UrlDeleteAjax".$this->m_nUniqid.",
        data: \"filename=\"+ filename,
        success: function(e,data){

        },
        fail: function(){

        }
        });
            return false;
        },

    loadScript:function(scriptName){
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'component/form_2cc54ba3-27ee-4f53-b9ff-6d06a35157b4/resources/jcrop/'+scriptName;
      $('jcrop').append(script);
    },

        init: function() {
            cropboxState".$this->m_nUniqid." = 'edit';

      bForceAdd = ($('#img_".$this->m_nUniqid."').attr('src').indexOf('photo_default.png') > 0 || $('#img_".$this->m_nUniqid."').attr('src').indexOf('logo_default.png') > 0);
            if(!bForceAdd && $('#img_".$this->m_nUniqid."').length > 0)
                cropboxState".$this->m_nUniqid." = 'edit';
            else
                cropboxState".$this->m_nUniqid." = 'add';
        },

        resizeColorbox:function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $.colorbox.autoResize();
            }, 100);
        },

        getPictureNameFromJSON:function(data){
            var json = data.jqXHR.responseText;
            json = json.replace('[','');
            json = json.replace(']','');
            json = $.parseJSON(json);
            return json.name;
        },

        getErrorMessageFromJson:function(data){
            return data.jqXHR.responseText;
        },

        getRandomNumbers:function(length, special){
            var iteration = 0;
        var result = \"\";
        var randomNumber;
        if(special == undefined){
        var special = false;
        }
            while(iteration < length){
            randomNumber = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) % 94) + 33;
            if(!special){
            if ((randomNumber >=33) && (randomNumber <=47)) { continue; }
            if ((randomNumber >=58) && (randomNumber <=64)) { continue; }
            if ((randomNumber >=91) && (randomNumber <=96)) { continue; }
            if ((randomNumber >=123) && (randomNumber <=126)) { continue; }
            }
            iteration++;
            result += String.fromCharCode(randomNumber);
        }
        return result;
        }
    }


    //BEGIN
    functions.init();

    container".$this->m_nUniqid.".attr('id', 'container".$this->m_nUniqid."');

    if(cropboxState".$this->m_nUniqid." == 'edit')// si l'utilisateur a deja une photo
  {
    //on vire le champ d'upload
      $('#fileupload').remove();
      $('#delmyimgajax_".$this->m_nUniqid."').show();

      picname".$this->m_nUniqid." = $('#img_".$this->m_nUniqid."').attr('src').split('/').pop();
      picname".$this->m_nUniqid." = picname".$this->m_nUniqid.".split('?')[0];
      picpath".$this->m_nUniqid." = '".$this->m_sSavePicturePath."'+picname".$this->m_nUniqid.";

      var deleteContainer".$this->m_nUniqid." = $('#delmyimgajax_".$this->m_nUniqid."').parent();

      functions.load();

  }
  else if(cropboxState".$this->m_nUniqid." == 'add')
  {
    //sinon on charge le necessaire a l'upload
        $('#launchcropbtn_".$this->m_nUniqid."').parent().append('<container></container>')
        $('#fileupload').attr('data-url',UrlUploadAjax".$this->m_nUniqid.");

        //fonctionne sur firefox
        if($.browser.mozilla)
            $('#fileupload').click();

        //BEGIN UPLOAD
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType : 'json',
            cache: false,
            done : function(e, data) {

                if($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera){
                    picname".$this->m_nUniqid." = data.files[0].name;

                }
                else{
                    picname".$this->m_nUniqid." = functions.getPictureNameFromJSON(data);
                }

                functions.load();
            },
            fail : function(e, data) {

                var response;

                if($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera){
                    response = 'This file can\'t be uploaded.</br>Please select a valide picture file.</br> Limits are : 600x600px / jpg, jpeg, png, gif / 2Mo'
                }
                else{
                    response = functions.getErrorMessageFromJson(data);
                }

                $('#fileupload').parent().prepend('<div class=\"errordiv\"><img src=\"' + jcropRessPath".$this->m_nUniqid." + 'warning.png\" alt=\"warning\"/><h3>' + response + '</h3></div>');
                $('#fileupload').fadeOut();
                $('.errordiv').fadeIn(1000);

                functions.resizeColorbox();
                setTimeout(function() { $('.errordiv').fadeOut(1000) }, 4000);
                setTimeout(function() { $('.errordiv').remove();$('#fileupload').fadeIn();functions.resizeColorbox();}, 4500);

            }
        });
  }


  $('#btndeleteyes').click(function(){

  });

  $('#cboxClose').click(function(){
    if(cropboxState".$this->m_nUniqid." == 'add')
        functions.deletePicture(picname".$this->m_nUniqid.");
   $('cropscript').remove();
  });

    //VALIDATE
    $('#valid_crop').on('click', function(event)
    {
        $('#valid_crop').fadeOut();
        var crop_form".$this->m_nUniqid." = $('#cropfrm');
        var crop_values".$this->m_nUniqid." = {
            x : $('#x').val(),
            y : $('#y').val(),
            w : $('#w').val(),
            h : $('#h').val(),
            path : picname".$this->m_nUniqid.",
      input_thumb_picture_path : $('#input_thumb_picture_path').val(),
      input_fullsize_picture_path : $('#input_fullsize_picture_path').val()
        };

    var picturename;

        //envoyer les infos de crop en ajax
        //récupération réponse ajax dans data
        $.post(UrlCropAjax".$this->m_nUniqid.", crop_values".$this->m_nUniqid.", function(data)
        {
            picname".$this->m_nUniqid." = picname".$this->m_nUniqid.".split('?')[0];//on récupère le nom de l'image sans le &v=
            var newThumbPath".$this->m_nUniqid." = '".$this->m_sThumbPicturePath."_large/'+picname".$this->m_nUniqid.";
            picturename = picname".$this->m_nUniqid.";
            if(cropboxState".$this->m_nUniqid." == 'add')
            {
              $('#container".$this->m_nUniqid." div:first-child').remove();

                $('#delmyimgajax_".$this->m_nUniqid."').insertAfter($('#launchcropbtn_".$this->m_nUniqid."'));
                $('#delmyimgajax_".$this->m_nUniqid."').fadeIn();
            }
            else if(cropboxState".$this->m_nUniqid." == 'edit')
            {
                $('#container".$this->m_nUniqid." div:first-child').remove();
            }

            $('<img src=\"' + newThumbPath".$this->m_nUniqid." + '?v=' +  event.timeStamp +'\" id=\"img_".$this->m_nUniqid."\"/>').prependTo('#container".$this->m_nUniqid."');
            $('#img_".$this->m_nUniqid."').wrapAll('<div class=\"login_picture_large\"></div>');

            cropboxState".$this->m_nUniqid." = 'edit';
            container".$this->m_nUniqid.".append($('#picname".$this->m_nUniqid."'));

      $('input[name=picname_".$this->m_nUniqid."]').attr('value', picname".$this->m_nUniqid.");
            $('#launchcropbtn_".$this->m_nUniqid."').html('Recadrer');

        });
        $('#colorbox').colorbox.close();
    });
    functions.resizeColorbox();
};
";

return $sJS;  }
```

I know that there is a lot of code, but i don't know where is coming the trouble ... I thought that it was when the URL of the picture was generated after pre-uploading... But i'm really not sure.

Best  regards,

Lukas

PS : Excuse me for my english, i'm french, i tried to do my best ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
if(is_file($this->m_sSrc))
{
   $sJS .= "$(function(event) { ";
   $sJS .= "  $('#delmyimgajax_".$this->m_nUniqid."').show();";
   $sJS .= "} ";
}
```

The last line doesn't close the brackets, it should be:

```
$sJS .= "});";
```

Comment: Thanks you for the tips that resolve a part of the problem !
But I still have to reload two or three time the image in the loader for having it and for croping it !
By the way, I don't have to submit the image for croping it. So it was a part of the problem